# AccountManager blockingGetAuthToken gets stuck

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager, auth-token

I've been using the [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html)
as a base to create my own SyncAdapter. It seems to work well to add a new account, but once I want to get the authtoken with AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(... it gets stuck and then throws an OperarationCanceledException after a few minutes.

Does anyone have an Idea of what could be wrong here? The code is almost the same as the sample except I am authenticating towards my own server.

05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961): OperationCanceledExcetpion
05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961): android.accounts.OperationCanceledException
05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961):     at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.internalGetResult(AccountManager.java:1255)
05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961):     at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1260)
05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961):     at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask.getResult(AccountManager.java:1181)
05-24 23:00:23.258: ERROR/SyncAdapter(4961):     at android.accounts.AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(AccountManager.java:737)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blockingGetAuthToken` method is a helper that calls `getAuthToken` synchronously.

If you are accessing the network to retrieve the auth token you will be blocked until the request succeeds. You should check that you can access the network resource properly from within your application.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer did put me in the right direction. I didn't really understand the flow of the authentication until now. My problem was that my authenticator got stuck when confirming the password, not  because of network connectivity problems but when trying to get Preferences when context was null.

Answer (score 0):

originally method is a convenient way to get authtoken instead calling method **getAuthToken**.
have to make sure not in the mainthread by calling methed runOnUIthread. or you can call the default method getAuthToken and using callback for execute next instruction. for the example.

```
final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(account, AccountConfig.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, null, this, null, null);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
                final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN); 
                if (authtoken == null) { 
                    return;
                }
                 // this callback interface method 
                logoutCallback.onLogoutFinished(authtoken);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```